# Zeitwerk error on devise mailer in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, mailer, zeitwerk

I have Rails 6, my preview class located in

**mailer/previews/devise_mailer_preview.rb**:

```
class DeviseMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  ...
end
```

And when I run application locally, everything is going fine, I can see my email previews on `http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/devise_mailer/confirmation_instructions` address. But now Im trying to deploy application on server, and found that when I run `bundle exec rails c production`, I got the error:

> /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader/callbacks.rb:17:in
> `on_file_autoloaded': expected file
> /home/deploy/project/releases/20200627024908/app/mailer/previews/devise_mailer_preview.rb
> to define constant Previews::DeviseMailerPreview, but didn't
> (Zeitwerk::NameError)

After that I've checked locally `RAILS_ENV=production rails c`, and got same.

If I will rename DeviseMailerPreview class to Previews::DeviseMailerPreview, it will be broken and I cannot see emails on development, because Rails 6, accordingly to [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#previewing-emails), expect exactly that name.

More of that, I've found in [this article](https://medium.com/cedarcode/understanding-zeitwerk-in-rails-6-f168a9f09a1f), that zeitwerk can be configured with `autoload_paths` param to avoid ruby's NameError. I found that I have it my **config/application.rb**:

```
config.load_defaults 6.0
```

Anyway I tried to add same row in my **config/environments/production.rb** file, but it didn't help.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Add `preview_path` to the `autoload_paths` and zeitwerk will expect `DeviseMailerPreview` constant to be defined.

```rb
# development.rb

config.action_mailer.preview_path = Rails.root.join("app/mailers/previews")
```

```rb
# application.rb

config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join("app/mailers/previews")
```

Comment: In my case was "spec/mailers/previews" but that did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 6, previews are added to the autoload paths only if `options.show_previews` is true, which is not by default in the production environment. See the source code [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-0-stable/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/railtie.rb#L62-L68).

The reason for this is that previews are supposed to be an aid for development, and they are generally not something you want to be able to look at in production.

However, you can set that flag to `true` in production if you want.

There's another derivative: By storing the previews under `app/mailers`, Rails is going to eager load them because `app/mailers` is in the autoload paths. If `app/mailers/previews` is not in the autoload paths, eager loading will fail due to the namespace mismatch. Either you have them enabled in all environments, or else is better to have them in a separate location, like the default.

Answer (score 0):

Your Mailer preview file is located in `mailer/previews/devise_mailer_preview.rb`, so I'm assuming it's full path is `app/mailer/previews/devise_mailer_preview.rb`

The docs says

> In the above example, the preview class for `UserMailer` should be named `UserMailerPreview` and located in `test/mailers/previews/user_mailer_preview.rb`

So put your `devise_mailer_preview.rb` file to `test/mailers/previews/devise_mailer_preview.rb`

or in your `config/application.rb` add this line and restart:

```rb
config.action_mailer.preview_path = "#{Rails.root}/app/mailers/previews"
```

Actually the answer was in the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#previewing-emails) itself.

Comment: I've try it, it doesn't work. And if you will take a look at the error message, Zeitwerk expect to find constant Previews::DeviseMailerPreview in `.../app/mailer/previews/devise_mailer_preview.rb`, nor test nor spec directory

Comment: @RuslanValeev what is the full path of your `devise_mailer_preview.rb` file? i.e. Where is it located?

Comment: `app/mailer/previews/devise_mailer_preview.rb` @cdadityang

Comment: Can you try with removing `config.action_mailer.preview_path` from `application.rb`, then moving `devise_mailer_preview.rb` to `test/mailers/previews/devise_mailer_preview.rb` or incase of rspec `spec/mailers/previews/devise_mailer_preview.rb` and then see if that works?